# How Display image based upon selected value?

Tags: objective-c

In my DropDown menu i implement table & it contain  3 cell &  Name( 5, 3, 1)

my QUE is : suppose if user select first  cell from table  (name is 5 ) then in homescreen  show 5 image . if i select  second cell (Name is 3)
then it show 3 image

dropdown list is implemented .

If any one know please help I am fresher

Comment: Please share what you did so far and what exactly didn't work for you.

Comment: Yep, will need to see some code here.